# Why I get "error: ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘std’"?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I try to compile this code from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

int add(int first, int second) { return first + second; }

template<typename T>
T add_generic(T first, T second) { return first + second; }

auto add_lambda = [](auto first, auto second) { return first + second; };

int main()
{
    // OK
    std::cout << std::apply(add, std::make_pair(1, 2)) << '\n';

   // Error: can't deduce the function type
   // std::cout << std::apply(add_generic, std::make_pair(2.0f, 3.0f)) << '\n'; 

   // OK
   std::cout << std::apply(add_lambda, std::make_pair(2.0f, 3.0f)) << '\n'; 
}
```

And I get this error:

```
toy.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
toy.cpp:15:18: error: ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘std’
     std::cout << std::apply(add, std::make_pair(1, 2)) << '\n';
                  ^~~
toy.cpp:21:18: error: ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘std’
     std::cout << std::apply(add_lambda, std::make_pair(2.0f, 3.0f)) << '\n';
```

I compile with this command:
`g++ -std=c++17 toy.cpp -o toy`

Here is my version of g++:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)
```

I also tried with clang but I have the same error. My version of clang is:

```
clang version 8.0.0 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /etc/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade your G++ compiler to at least 7 version, or use

```
#include <experimental/tuple>
```

then call

```
std::cout << std::experimental::apply(add, std::make_pair(1, 2)) << '\n';
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/xIzbD8)

Comment: Why should I use <experimental/tuple> and not <tuple> as written in the documentation?

Comment: Even if your compiler g++6.3 supports mode `-std=c++17` it doesn't mean that all features of C++ standard library are covered by it. `apply` is one of them. As I said, upgrade compiler to version which handles it fully, or use the code from `experimental`. [Under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318493/are-the-experimental-features-of-modern-c-reliable-for-long-term-projects) you can read what is the intention of `experimental`.