# How to get parent folder from path in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using C++ in linux and I want to extract the parent folder from a path in C++ 14.

For example, I have the path likes

```
/home/abc/fi.mp4
```

My expected output be `abc`. How can I do it in C++

This is that I did

```
std::string getFolderName(const std::string &path) {
    size_t found = path.find_last_of("/\\");
    string foldername = ...
    return foldername;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
// Returns the path-string without the filename part
std::string getFolderPath(const std::string &path) {
   const size_t found = path.find_last_of("/\\");
   return (found == string::npos) ? path : path.substr(0, found);
}

// Returns only the filename part (after the last slash)
std::string getFileName(const std::string & path) {
   const size_t found = path.find_last_of("/\\");
   return (found == string::npos) ? path : path.substr(found+1);
}
```

Comment: so if I want to get `home`, how can I change your code

Comment: `getFolderName("/home/abc/fi.mp4")` will return "/home/abc".  You could then call `getFolderName()` on that returned string (i.e. `getFolderName("/home/abc")`) and that will return "/home".

Comment: Come back to original question, `getFolderName("/home/abc/fi.mp4") will return "/home/abc"`==> But I want to get "abc" only

Comment: I updated my answer -- call `getFolderPath("/home/abc/fi.mp4")` to get "/home/abc", then call `getFileName("/home/abc")` to get "abc".

Comment: I called  both but it does not work for getFileName. Could you check it

Comment: ok it worked with your new modification

Comment: I tried to get `home` but it does not work as your suggestion
>getFolderName("/home/abc/fi.mp4") will return "/home/abc". You could then call getFolderName() on that returned string (i.e. getFolderName("/home/abc")) and that will return "/home"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [`experimental`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem) version of `std::filesystem` was already available in **C++14**.

If it is indeed available in your environment, you can use [`parent_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/parent_path) to get the parent folder from a [`path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path). Then you can use the method [`filename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/filename) to extract the name without the full path specification.
In order to convert a `path` to `std::string` you can use the [`string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/string) method.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    std::string path_str = "/home/abc/fi.mp4";
    std::experimental::filesystem::path p = path_str;
    std::experimental::filesystem::path parent_p = p.parent_path();
    std::experimental::filesystem::path parent_p_fname = p.parent_path().filename();
    std::string result_str = parent_p_fname.string();
    std::cout << result_str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
```

You can further use `parent_path()` to climb up the hirarchy.

Once **C++17** is available for you, you can simply drop the `experimental` prefix.

Comment: I updated my answer with info about the `path::filename()` method that extract the folder name without full path specification.

Comment: Afaik the experimental library headers are non standard, thus their function is not properly defined nor guaranteed. Probably shouldn't use them in production code.

Comment: Thanks it looks good, but if my input is std::string, so how can I do it with the line     std::experimental::filesystem::path p = "/home/abc/fi.mp4";

Comment: I've been using `std::experimental::filesystem` for some years (also in production code after testing), with 0 problems. It was also a good preparation for upgrading to C++17. Having said that - I agree some caution is required. I guess the OP can test it and decide how stable/reliable it is in his case.

Comment: @KimHee you can simply assign the `std::string` into the `path` variable. Will update my answer. To convert back - call `string()` method as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Here's a very good thread on `std::experimental`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322001/11770674

Comment: @RL-S Thanks for the link. I understand that in general `experimental` fetaures are something you can use "at your own risk". It is not guarenteed to be supported by all compilers, and might change when/if will be added to the standard. However - `experimental::filesystem` specifically came from boost (where it was used for some time), and also evetuanlly found it's way into the standard (with C++17). IMHO the risk of using it (if your compiler supports it) is very low. Of course testing is required, and some discretion when using it in production code.

Comment: I think using `std::experimental` from an *older* standard, for a feature that was fully included in a *newer* standard, is very safe. The link was for further reading for the OP author :)

Answer (score 0):

The function getFolders will get you all the folder names in a path.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    
vector<string> getFolders(const char* path) {
        vector<string> folders;
        stringstream ss;
        int i = 0, k = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = *(path + i)) != '\0') {
            if (c != '/'){
                ss << c;
                ++k;
            }
            else {
                if (k > 0){
                    folders.push_back(ss.str());
                    ss.str(string());
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return folders;
    }
    void main()
    {
        vector<string> folders = getFolders("/home/abc/fi.mp4");
        for (auto f : folders){
            cout << f << endl;
        }
    }
```